# Searching in a json in python

Tags: python, json

I am using requests.get to get an output.[{"id": "e644b06c-8f5b-4bdf-84a0-7266dffc6979", "securityResourceId": "e48e8536-02ff-424d-856a-dab30af23919", "name": "helloWorld",  So in the name tag i need to search if it contains xyz and if it does append that name to an array.If you could help id be obliged.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can add .json() to the end of a request to get a dict out of that request (if the request returned a json).

```
arr = []
dict = requests.get('website').json()
if 'xyz' in dict.get('name'):
    arr.append(dict['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can parse JSON into `dictionary` using `json` library.

after that you can search the contents with either `re` or `fuzzywuzzy` to get matching pattern.

snippet:

```
import json, re
input_string = '[{"test":"something"},{"xyz":"something else","foo":"bar"}]'
obj = json.loads(input_string)
arr = []
for item in obj:
   for key in item:
       match = re.match("xyz",key)
       if match is not None:
          arr.append(item)
          continue
```